# "unknown option: --output" after updating Android SDK from revision 12 to revision 13

Tags: android, ant, proguard

I've just updated my android development tools to revision 13.  This all went smoothly and I can continue to build in eclipse as usual.

However once I try to de a release build with ant my build fails with the message "unknown option: --output".

Further Info: I'm running 32bit Eclipse / Java on 64 bit windows. The issue occurs only when running a build from the command line and the build worked before I updated the sdk from revision 12 to 13.

Here is the relevant output from "ant release"

```
 [proguard] Printing classes to [C:\Work\bugsy_workspace\bugsy\bin\proguard\dump.txt]...

-dex:
     [echo] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Work\bugsy_workspace\bugsy\bin\classes.dex...
    [apply] unknown option: --output
    [apply] usage:
    [apply]   dx --dex [--debug] [--verbose] [--positions=<style>] [--no-locals]
    [apply]   [--no-optimize] [--statistics] [--[no-]optimize-list=<file>] [--no-strict]
    [apply]   [--keep-classes] [--output=<file>] [--dump-to=<file>] [--dump-width=<n>]
    [apply]   [--dump-method=<name>[*]] [--verbose-dump] [--no-files] [--core-library]
    [apply]   [--num-threads=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.{zip,jar,apk} | <directory>] ...
    [apply]     Convert a set of classfiles into a dex file, optionally embedded in a
    [apply]     jar/zip. Output name must end with one of: .dex .jar .zip .apk. Positions
    [apply]     options: none, important, lines.
    [apply]   dx --annotool --annotation=<class> [--element=<element types>]
    [apply]   [--print=<print types>]
    [apply]   dx --dump [--debug] [--strict] [--bytes] [--optimize]
    [apply]   [--basic-blocks | --rop-blocks | --ssa-blocks | --dot] [--ssa-step=<step>]
    [apply]   [--width=<n>] [<file>.class | <file>.txt] ...
    [apply]     Dump classfiles, or transformations thereof, in a human-oriented format.
    [apply]   dx --junit [-wait] <TestClass>
    [apply]     Run the indicated unit test.
    [apply]   dx -J<option> ... <arguments, in one of the above forms>
    [apply]     Pass VM-specific options to the virtual machine that runs dx.
    [apply]   dx --version
    [apply]     Print the version of this tool (1.6).
    [apply]   dx --help
    [apply]     Print this message.

BUILD FAILED
C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:487: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:203: apply returned: 1

Total time: 12 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get to the bottom of this myself.  Android SDK Tools Revision 13 requires Android SDK Platform-tools revision 7.

There are some instructions on how to get & install platform-tools 7 [here.](http://brettsdevblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-sdk-revision-13-pain.html)